# Cannot SSH onto my PI using my domain name instead of IP

Tags: ssh, dns

I have a domain name’s DNS configured with cloudflare that sets the A record to my public IP address (I’ve set DDNS so I can SSH onto my raspberry pi if my dynamic IP ever changes). However, for some reason I cannot seem to ssh onto my pi using my domain name.

This way works (both with my public or private IP on port 4321):

```
ssh nick@2.127.***.*** -i ./.ssh/rpi_key -p 4321
```

However, for some reason this doesn’t work:

```
ssh nick@mycustomdomain.co.uk -i ./.ssh/rpi_key -p 4321
```

Why does this happen, and how can I get SSH to work using my domain name rather than IP? Cloudflare clearly points the IP to 2.127.***.*** so I assume this should be completely identical.

[image: cloudflare dns records]

Also, after browsing some other posts, they suggest running this command: `dig +short "mycustomdomain.co.uk" @8.8.8.8`, which returns the following:

```
104.21.**.***
172.67.***.**
```

I’d assume it should return the IP associated with that domain name (my public IP, 2.127.***.***), but instead it returns different IPs and 2 of them. Am I incorrect here? I can only assume otherwise they return the NS IPs of Cloudflare.

What am I not getting here? Thanks for any help

Comment: looks like a DNS propagation issue - i.e. your Dynamic IP address isn't propagating throughout the DNS system in a timely manner

Comment: But why is the dig command returning 2 different IPs? If it's a propagation issue then would I need to just wait a bit longer for the problem to fix itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else having this it turns out that the problem was Cloudflare's DNS settings set to being proxied; changing to DNS only works